# inquire of plant's wellbeing

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-usage

For example:

> I wonder **how my plant might be doing/might be bearing up**, since I've neglected it for a week.

Meaning, I wonder what state my plant might be in when I come back home (dried out, grown in size, etc.).

Are both examples correct? Do they sound normal? Are there better ways to express that?

Comment: or **holding up**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say both and still be correct, but to me saying "might be doing" sounds more natural, because people usually do not say "bearing up" when referring to a plant. However, both are acceptable, so you have the choice between the two.